# How do I multiply a price in PHP and keep the zeroes at the end?

Tags: php, ajax, math, cart

I'm building a simple e-commerse site in php. In the cart where the product prices are added, I simply multiply them ie. $totalPrice=$price * $qty, but, any zero's at the end get chopped off. It's ok if the total price of items is, say.. $10.52, but any zero's don't display after they've been muliplied.

Here is the url to my site www.allthingsskin.com.au

If you add an item to the cart you'll see what I'm trying to explain.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks

Mark

Comment: No offence, but if you're a novice to PHP, you might want to consider using one of the off the shelf e-commerce systems.

Comment: in google chrome 11 (beta) the nav bar is not displaying correctly - the background image on `body` is not lined up correctly, causing it to appear "twice". I'd post a screenshot but I'm lazy.

Comment: Just so you know, to prevent rounding errors, you should store and  calculate all prices in their lowest whole integer value, like pennies, then divide by 100 for display.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to use ZenCart and a few others, I just wanted something simple and versatile. Oddly enough, I didn't find it particularly difficult to make my own in php, even with virtuly no programming or web developing expereicene, but I did find it almost immposible to use some of the 'easy to use' off the shelf shopping carts.

Comment: @ross, thanks ross. at the moment the background is more or less just a PSD and I havent split it up yet as I'm still working on the design.

Answer (score 7):

[number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) is the function you are looking for.  The first parameter is your total, the 2nd parameter is the number of decimal places.

```
echo number_format(10, 2); // returns 10.00
```

You can also use [money_format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php).

Comment: Yup -- this is what I was going to reply with. +1 for thinking my thoughts :)

Comment: yeah, money_format did the trick, works perfectly now. Thanks to everyone who replied!